# GraphQL-SPQR - Error with List without generics

Tags: graphql-spqr

My GraphQL schema is:

```
//Schema generated from query classes
GraphQLSchema schema = new GraphQLSchemaGenerator()
        .withBasePackages("com.blah.blah")
        .withOperationBuilder(new DefaultOperationBuilder(DefaultOperationBuilder.TypeInference.UNLIMITED))
        .withOutputConverters((config, defaults) -> defaults.drop(ObjectScalarAdapter.class))
        .withResolverBuilders(new AnnotatedResolverBuilder())
        .withOperationsFromSingleton(myObjectQuery)
        .withTypeTransformer(new DefaultTypeTransformer(true, true))
        .withValueMapperFactory(new JacksonValueMapperFactory())
        .generate();
```

I have a GraphQLQuery defined:

```
@GraphQLQuery(name = "getMyObject")
public MyObject getMyObject() {}
```

which returns a "MyObject" class

the MyObject class does not use generics and is defined as follows (I cannot change it), although I know that **myList** contains objects of type **MyListType**:

```
public class MyObject {
    private List myList;
    public List getMyList() {
        return myList;
    }
}
```

Using Graph*i*QL (assume the fields are valid):

```
{
  getMyObject() {
    id
    myList{
      myListTypeId
    }
  }
}
```

Results in:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Validation error of type SubSelectionNotAllowed: Sub selection not allowed on leaf type null of field myList@ 'getMyObject/myList'",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 4,
          "column": 5
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I resolve this error?  I added an aspect to coerce the return result from getMylist() to be a List but obviously that had no effect on the validation step.

Question is:
How do I configure the schema to allow for getters that return non-generics Lists or Maps?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it @GraphQLQuery needs to be added to the getter.

```
public class MyObject {
    private List myList;
    @GraphQLQuery(name = "myList")
    public List getMyList() {
        return myList;
    }
}
```

As you mentioned you might not be able to change this. One way may be to create a wrapper object, so rather than returning MyObject, you return MyWrapperObject, which takes a MyObject in constructor and has SPQR compatible getters to access the varaibles.
Alternatively there is @GraphQLContext, which you can use to add (without changing the class) new  methods. These methods can be SPQR compatible.

Hope that helps